# Generic procedure reference

Tags: fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I trying to compile a fortran module Y that contains a function and a subroutine that both calls the same subroutine X. When this module is compiled I get the following error:

```
array_lib.F90(70): error #8032: Generic procedure reference has two or
more specific procedure with the same type/rank/keyword signature. [MRGRNK]
        CALL mrgrnk(list,idx)
-------------^
array_lib.F90(141): error #8032: Generic procedure reference has two or
more specific procedure with the same type/rank/keyword signature. [MRGRNK]
        CALL mrgrnk(xarr,ist)
```

Can someone explain a bit what's going on here. I don't understand what's wrong?

I appreciate some insight on this.

Code:

```
MODULE array_lib
USE PARKIND1  ,ONLY : JPIM, JPIB, JPRB

IMPLICIT NONE

CONTAINS

FUNCTION infind(list,val,sort,dist)
USE m_mrgrnk
IMPLICIT NONE

! ----- INPUTS -----
REAL(KIND=JPRB), DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: list
REAL(KIND=JPRB), INTENT(IN) :: val
INTEGER, INTENT(IN), OPTIONAL :: sort

! ----- OUTPUTS -----
INTEGER(JPIM) :: infind
REAL(KIND=JPRB), INTENT(OUT), OPTIONAL :: dist

! ----- INTERNAL -----
REAL(KIND=JPRB), DIMENSION(SIZE(list)) :: lists
INTEGER(JPIM) :: nlist, result, tmp(1), sort_list
INTEGER(JPIM), DIMENSION(SIZE(list)) :: mask, idx

IF (PRESENT(sort)) THEN
    sort_list = sort
ELSE
    sort_list = 0
END IF

nlist = SIZE(list)
IF (sort_list == 1) THEN
    CALL mrgrnk(list,idx)
    lists = list(idx)
ELSE
    lists = list
END IF

IF (val >= lists(nlist)) THEN
    result = nlist
ELSE IF (val <= lists(1)) THEN
    result = 1
ELSE
    mask(:) = 0
    WHERE (lists < val) mask = 1
    tmp = MINLOC(mask,1)
    IF (ABS(lists(tmp(1)-1)-val) < ABS(lists(tmp(1))-val)) THEN
        result = tmp(1) - 1
    ELSE
        result = tmp(1)
    END IF
END IF
IF (PRESENT(dist)) dist = lists(result)-val
IF (sort_list == 1) THEN
    infind = idx(result)
ELSE
    infind = result
END IF

END FUNCTION infind

! ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
! SUBROUTINE LIN_INTERPOLATE
! ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUBROUTINE lin_interpolate(yarr,xarr,yyarr,xxarr,tol)
    USE m_mrgrnk
    IMPLICIT NONE

! ----- INPUTS -----
    REAL(KIND=JPRB), DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: yarr, xarr, xxarr
    REAL(KIND=JPRB), INTENT(IN) :: tol

! ----- OUTPUTS -----
    REAL(KIND=JPRB), DIMENSION(SIZE(xxarr)), INTENT(OUT) :: yyarr

! ----- INTERNAL -----
    REAL(KIND=JPRB), DIMENSION(SIZE(xarr)) :: ysort, xsort
    INTEGER(JPIM), DIMENSION(SIZE(xarr)) :: ist
    INTEGER(JPIM) :: nx, nxx, i, iloc
    REAL(KIND=JPRB) :: d, m

    nx = SIZE(xarr)
    nxx = SIZE(xxarr)

! // xsort, ysort are sorted versions of xarr, yarr
    CALL mrgrnk(xarr,ist)
    ysort = yarr(ist)
    xsort = xarr(ist)

    DO i=1,nxx
        iloc = infind(xsort,xxarr(i),dist=d)
        IF (d > tol) THEN
            PRINT *, 'interpolation error'
            STOP
        END IF
        IF (iloc == nx) THEN
        !     :: set to the last value
            yyarr(i) = ysort(nx)
        ELSE
        !     :: is there another CLOSEby value?
            IF (ABS(xxarr(i)-xsort(iloc+1)) < 2*tol) THEN
            !       :: yes, DO a linear interpolation
                m = (ysort(iloc+1)-ysort(iloc))/(xsort(iloc+1)-xsort(iloc))
                yyarr(i) = ysort(iloc) + m*(xxarr(i)-xsort(iloc))
            ELSE
            !       :: no, set to the only nearby value
                yyarr(i) = ysort(iloc)
            END IF
        END IF
    END DO

 END SUBROUTINE lin_interpolate

 END MODULE array_lib
```

The MODULE M_MRGRNK:

```
MODULE m_mrgrnk
USE PARKIND1  ,ONLY : JPIM, JPIB, JPRB

PUBLIC :: mrgrnk
!PRIVATE :: kdp
PRIVATE :: R_mrgrnk, I_mrgrnk, D_mrgrnk

INTERFACE mrgrnk
MODULE PROCEDURE D_mrgrnk, R_mrgrnk, I_mrgrnk
END INTERFACE mrgrnk

CONTAINS

SUBROUTINE D_mrgrnk (XDONT, IRNGT)
REAL(KIND=JPRB), DIMENSION (:), INTENT (IN) :: XDONT
INTEGER(KIND=JPIM), DIMENSION (:), INTENT (OUT) :: IRNGT
REAL(KIND=JPRB):: XVALA, XVALB

INTEGER(KIND=JPIM), DIMENSION (SIZE(IRNGT)) :: JWRKT
INTEGER(KIND=JPIM) :: LMTNA, LMTNC, IRNG1, IRNG2
INTEGER(KIND=JPIM) :: NVAL, IIND, IWRKD, IWRK, IWRKF, JINDA, IINDA, IINDB

NVAL = Min (SIZE(XDONT), SIZE(IRNGT))
SELECT CASE (NVAL)
CASE (:0)
RETURN
CASE (1)
IRNGT (1) = 1
RETURN
CASE DEFAULT
CONTINUE
END SELECT

DO IIND = 2, NVAL, 2
    IF (XDONT(IIND-1) <= XDONT(IIND)) THEN
        IRNGT (IIND-1) = IIND - 1
        IRNGT (IIND) = IIND
    ELSE
        IRNGT (IIND-1) = IIND
        IRNGT (IIND) = IIND - 1
    END IF
END DO
IF (MODULO(NVAL, 2) /= 0) THEN
    IRNGT (NVAL) = NVAL
END IF

LMTNA = 2
LMTNC = 4

DO
IF (NVAL <= 2) EXIT

DO IWRKD = 0, NVAL - 1, 4
    IF ((IWRKD+4) > NVAL) THEN
        IF ((IWRKD+2) >= NVAL) EXIT

        IF (XDONT(IRNGT(IWRKD+2)) <= XDONT(IRNGT(IWRKD+3))) EXIT

        IF (XDONT(IRNGT(IWRKD+1)) <= XDONT(IRNGT(IWRKD+3))) THEN
            IRNG2 = IRNGT (IWRKD+2)
            IRNGT (IWRKD+2) = IRNGT (IWRKD+3)
            IRNGT (IWRKD+3) = IRNG2
        ELSE
            IRNG1 = IRNGT (IWRKD+1)
            IRNGT (IWRKD+1) = IRNGT (IWRKD+3)
            IRNGT (IWRKD+3) = IRNGT (IWRKD+2)
            IRNGT (IWRKD+2) = IRNG1
        END IF
        EXIT
    END IF
    IF (XDONT(IRNGT(IWRKD+2)) <= XDONT(IRNGT(IWRKD+3))) CYCLE
    IF (XDONT(IRNGT(IWRKD+1)) <= XDONT(IRNGT(IWRKD+3))) THEN
        IRNG2 = IRNGT (IWRKD+2)
        IRNGT (IWRKD+2) = IRNGT (IWRKD+3)
        IF (XDONT(IRNG2) <= XDONT(IRNGT(IWRKD+4))) THEN
            IRNGT (IWRKD+3) = IRNG2
        ELSE
            IRNGT (IWRKD+3) = IRNGT (IWRKD+4)
            IRNGT (IWRKD+4) = IRNG2
        END IF
    ELSE
        IRNG1 = IRNGT (IWRKD+1)
        IRNG2 = IRNGT (IWRKD+2)
        IRNGT (IWRKD+1) = IRNGT (IWRKD+3)
        IF (XDONT(IRNG1) <= XDONT(IRNGT(IWRKD+4))) THEN
            IRNGT (IWRKD+2) = IRNG1
            IF (XDONT(IRNG2) <= XDONT(IRNGT(IWRKD+4))) THEN
                IRNGT (IWRKD+3) = IRNG2
            ELSE
                IRNGT (IWRKD+3) = IRNGT (IWRKD+4)
                IRNGT (IWRKD+4) = IRNG2
            END IF
        ELSE
            IRNGT (IWRKD+2) = IRNGT (IWRKD+4)
            IRNGT (IWRKD+3) = IRNG1
            IRNGT (IWRKD+4) = IRNG2
        END IF
    END IF
END DO

LMTNA = 4
EXIT
END DO

DO
IF (LMTNA >= NVAL) EXIT
IWRKF = 0
LMTNC = 2 * LMTNC

DO
IWRK = IWRKF
IWRKD = IWRKF + 1
JINDA = IWRKF + LMTNA
IWRKF = IWRKF + LMTNC
IF (IWRKF >= NVAL) THEN
    IF (JINDA >= NVAL) EXIT
    IWRKF = NVAL
END IF
IINDA = 1
IINDB = JINDA + 1

JWRKT (1:LMTNA) = IRNGT (IWRKD:JINDA)

XVALA = XDONT (JWRKT(IINDA))
XVALB = XDONT (IRNGT(IINDB))

DO
IWRK = IWRK + 1

IF (XVALA > XVALB) THEN
    IRNGT (IWRK) = IRNGT (IINDB)
    IINDB = IINDB + 1
    IF (IINDB > IWRKF) THEN
    !  Only A still with unprocessed values
        IRNGT (IWRK+1:IWRKF) = JWRKT (IINDA:LMTNA)
        EXIT
    END IF
    XVALB = XDONT (IRNGT(IINDB))
ELSE
    IRNGT (IWRK) = JWRKT (IINDA)
    IINDA = IINDA + 1
    IF (IINDA > LMTNA) EXIT! Only B still with unprocessed values
    XVALA = XDONT (JWRKT(IINDA))
END IF

END DO
END DO
LMTNA = 2 * LMTNA
END DO

RETURN

END SUBROUTINE D_mrgrnk

SUBROUTINE R_mrgrnk (XDONT, IRNGT)
REAL(KIND=JPRB), DIMENSION (:), INTENT (IN) :: XDONT
INTEGER(KIND=JPIM), DIMENSION (:), INTENT (OUT) :: IRNGT
REAL(KIND=JPRB) :: XVALA, XVALB

INTEGER(KIND=JPIM), DIMENSION (SIZE(IRNGT)) :: JWRKT
INTEGER(KIND=JPIM) :: LMTNA, LMTNC, IRNG1, IRNG2
INTEGER(KIND=JPIM) :: NVAL, IIND, IWRKD, IWRK, IWRKF, JINDA, IINDA, IINDB

NVAL = Min (SIZE(XDONT), SIZE(IRNGT))
SELECT CASE (NVAL)
CASE (:0)
RETURN
CASE (1)
IRNGT (1) = 1
RETURN
CASE DEFAULT
CONTINUE
END SELECT

DO IIND = 2, NVAL, 2
    IF (XDONT(IIND-1) <= XDONT(IIND)) THEN
        IRNGT (IIND-1) = IIND - 1
        IRNGT (IIND) = IIND
    ELSE
        IRNGT (IIND-1) = IIND
        IRNGT (IIND) = IIND - 1
    END IF
END DO
IF (MODULO(NVAL, 2) /= 0) THEN
    IRNGT (NVAL) = NVAL
END IF
LMTNA = 2
LMTNC = 4
DO
IF (NVAL <= 2) EXIT
DO IWRKD = 0, NVAL - 1, 4
    IF ((IWRKD+4) > NVAL) THEN
        IF ((IWRKD+2) >= NVAL) EXIT
        IF (XDONT(IRNGT(IWRKD+2)) <= XDONT(IRNGT(IWRKD+3))) EXIT
        IF (XDONT(IRNGT(IWRKD+1)) <= XDONT(IRNGT(IWRKD+3))) THEN
            IRNG2 = IRNGT (IWRKD+2)
            IRNGT (IWRKD+2) = IRNGT (IWRKD+3)
            IRNGT (IWRKD+3) = IRNG2
        ELSE
            IRNG1 = IRNGT (IWRKD+1)
            IRNGT (IWRKD+1) = IRNGT (IWRKD+3)
            IRNGT (IWRKD+3) = IRNGT (IWRKD+2)
            IRNGT (IWRKD+2) = IRNG1
        END IF
        EXIT
    END IF
    IF (XDONT(IRNGT(IWRKD+2)) <= XDONT(IRNGT(IWRKD+3))) Cycle
    IF (XDONT(IRNGT(IWRKD+1)) <= XDONT(IRNGT(IWRKD+3))) THEN
        IRNG2 = IRNGT (IWRKD+2)
        IRNGT (IWRKD+2) = IRNGT (IWRKD+3)
        IF (XDONT(IRNG2) <= XDONT(IRNGT(IWRKD+4))) THEN
        !   1 3 2 4
            IRNGT (IWRKD+3) = IRNG2
        ELSE
        !   1 3 4 2
            IRNGT (IWRKD+3) = IRNGT (IWRKD+4)
            IRNGT (IWRKD+4) = IRNG2
        END IF
    ELSE
```

Comment: The error message is quite explicit and tells you exactly where in your source file the problem occurs.  You have defined 2 subroutines with the same signature.  But how do you expect any more help than this without showing your code ?

Comment: Apologies. I added the code now.

Comment: Can you post the interface block for `mrgrnk` in module `m_mrgrnk` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There issues here is :

- The specific interfaces with your generic interface must be unique (type/rank/etc must not be identical).

Specifically, what is happening is that your module procedures do not appear distinct, so when you:

```
CALL mrgrnk(xarr,ist)
```

the compiler cannot determine which specific module procedure to invoke.

Your generic interface is

```
INTERFACE mrgrnk
  MODULE PROCEDURE D_mrgrnk, R_mrgrnk, I_mrgrnk
END INTERFACE mrgrnk
```

and your specific interfaces are

```
SUBROUTINE D_mrgrnk (XDONT, IRNGT)
   REAL(KIND=JPRB), DIMENSION (:), INTENT (IN) :: XDONT
   INTEGER(KIND=JPIM), DIMENSION (:), INTENT (OUT) :: IRNGT
END SUBROUTINE

SUBROUTINE R_mrgrnk (XDONT, IRNGT)
   REAL(KIND=JPRB), DIMENSION (:), INTENT (IN) :: XDONT
   INTEGER(KIND=JPIM), DIMENSION (:), INTENT (OUT) :: IRNGT
END SUBROUTINE

SUBROUTINE I_mrgrnk (XDONT, IRNGT)
  INTEGER(KIND=JPIM), DIMENSION (:), INTENT (IN)  :: XDONT
  INTEGER(KIND=JPIM), DIMENSION (:), INTENT (OUT) :: IRNGT
END SUBROUTINE
```

As you can see the interfaces to `D__mrgrnk` and `R_mrgrnk` are the same and when you call `mrgrnk` with arguments of type `REAL(KIND=JPRB)` and `INTEGER(KIND=JPIM)`, the compiler cannot determine which procedure to call.  In order to fix this, you need to differentiate the types of the arguments to `D__mrgrnk` and `R_mrgrnk` and based upon their naming, the way you probably want to do this is to make `D__mrgrnk` take a real type that is double precision while `R_mrgrnk` takes a real that is single precision.

Comment: I'm a bit new when it comes to these more subtle kind of errors. This code has been translated from F77 to Fortran 90. Are you saying that in the module, I cannot have a function and subroutine defined?

Comment: @Shejo284 you certainly can do that.  The error you provided is not complaining about that, it is complaining that you have a generic `interface` block that has two specific interfaces declared that are not unique.  You can have whatever procedures and functions you want in a module, but there are more stringent rules within a generic interface.  The error isn't in the code you posted, it is likely in module m_mrgnk.

Comment: Here's the part of the module the mrgrnk() interface is defined:
    MODULE m_mrgrnk
    USE PARKIND1  ,ONLY : JPIM, JPIB, JPRB
    PUBLIC :: mrgrnk
    PRIVATE :: R_mrgrnk, I_mrgrnk, D_mrgrnk    
    INTERFACE mrgrnk
    MODULE PROCEDURE D_mrgrnk, R_mrgrnk, I_mrgrnk
    END INTERFACE mrgrnk
    CONTAINS snip....

The m_mrgrnk module is too long to post here and I don't know how to attach a file here. I've looked in these files. I didn't write the file, I'm only trying to update them to F90 and fix any bugs. All the subroutines in m_mrgrnk are defined with different names.

Comment: @Shejo284 can you edit that into your Q along with the interfaces for D_mrgrnk, R_mrgrnk, I_mrgrnk ?  Your compiler is complaining that those three are not distinct, so to help we need to see what the arguments for each are.

Comment: MODULE m_mrgrnk USE PARKIND1 ,ONLY : JPIM, JPIB, JPRB 
    PUBLIC :: mrgrnk       
    PRIVATE :: R_mrgrnk, I_mrgrnk, D_mrgrnk 
    INTERFACE mrgrnk MODULE PROCEDURE D_mrgrnk, R_mrgrnk, I_mrgrnk 
    END INTERFACE mrgrnk 
    CONTAINS 
    SUBROUTINE D_mrgrnk (XDONT, IRNGT)
    END SUBROUTINE D_mrgrnk
    SUBROUTINE R_mrgrnk (XDONT, IRNGT)
    END SUBROUTINE R_mrgrnk
    SUBROUTINE I_mrgrnk (XDONT, IRNGT)
    END SUBROUTINE I_mrgrnk
    END MODULE m_mrgrnk

Comment: @Shejo284 it would greatly increase the readability if you could put this stuff into your Question and not in these comments.  Also, are these the complete subroutines or are the variables such as XDONT, IRNGT declared as well?  At a minimum when you edit your Q, please add the above information including the way those arguments are declared.

Comment: Ok, apologies for the clumsy way I did this. Now both complete modules are posted in the Q. Included are all the declarations for the arguments.

Comment: Ah...now I understand. It is strange to call a function based on precision of the argument. I'm new to fortran and never encountered something like this before. The mistake crept in when I tried to make all the code of a single kind real and kind integer. I'm grateful for the help!